# Which R versions does Renjin support?

Tags: java, renjin

I could not find either in the documentation http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/library/execution-context.html or here any information on how to configure an specific R version. Is there a way to configure the Session or the RenjinScriptEngine with a R version? If not, is 3.5 the latest version supported?

Answer (score 0):

The latest Renjin release is 3.5-beta76, and that is compatible with GNU R 3.5.3.